# How can I extract the text/numbers to the right of a specific character (when there are multiple of the same character)?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to extract the numbers after the final semicolon in a particular field (they relate to subdivided lots of land parcels). I have tried a variation of some answers I have found here but they don't entirely fit the bill. See below for a data samples.

[image: Data Sample]

[image: Data Sample 2]

Comment: In Python that would be *field*`.split(';')[-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to approach it.  Taking an approach similar to what Vince mentions in the comments (replace "Name" with name of field):

```
string_to_array("Name",';')[-1]
```

There is also at least one regular expression approach, although regular expressions are probably overkill in this situation.

```
regexp_matches("Name", '.*;(\\p{N}+(?:,+\\p{N}+)*)$')[0]
```

Breaking down the regular expression:

> .  **Dot.** Matches any character except line breaks.
>   *  **Quantifier.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
> ;  **Character.** Matches a ";" character (char code 59).
> (  **Capturing group #1.** Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.
>   \p{N}  **Unicode category.** Matches any character in the 'Number' unicode category.
>     +  **Quantifier.** Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
>   (?:  **Non-capturing group.** Groups multiple tokens together without creating a capture group.
>     ,  **Character.** Matches a "," character (char code 44).
>         +    **Quantifier.** Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
>     \p{N}  **Unicode category.** Matches any character in the 'Number' unicode category.
>       +  **Quantifier.** Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
>     )
>       *  **Quantifier.** Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
> )

Comment: This was very helpful and solved the problem. Appreciate the breakdown as well.